# After replacing watir with watir-webdriver in ruby project application is executing slowly

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I have replaced watir with watir-webdriver recent version and found that application objects are getting identified very slowly.

Any breakthough we have found till now? Because i saw issues 57 and 108 on Github of watir-webdriver, but they are closed and answer is not satisfactory.

Somebody can suggest even if this can be solved with cucumber.

Comment: Are all tests running slow? Are there any examples of scripts that are running slow? 

I've found that Watir-Webdriver tends to run slow when I depend on regular expressions to identify elements.

Comment: yes..all tests are running slow. On my login page i have one text box. I have used :id to identify it and not using reg expression. Below is my Login class class LoginPage

   def initialize(browser)
     @ie = browser

  end


   def login_with_user_id(userid)

     @ie.text_field(:id, 'username').set userid
    @ie.button(:value, 'Login').click
      end
  end